# How is this code in C about threads supposed to work?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am taking an Operating Systems class, and the book provides this code.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void * mythread(void *arg) {
   int m = (int) arg;
   printf("%d\n", m);
   return (void*) (arg + 1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t p;
    int rc, m;
    pthread_create(&p, NULL, mythread, (void*) 100);
    pthread_join(p, (void**) &m);
    printf("returned %d\n", m);
    return 0;
}
```

The things I can't wrap my head around are:
1- How can you use "(void *) 100"? 
2- Inside of the function mythread, is it possible to cast arg, which is a  void pointer, into an int. Is that code supposed to work like that? If so, can you please explain how?
Here's the link to the source: [Chapter 27](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/threads-api.pdf) page 5. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Converting between integers and pointers is implementation-defined, according to [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.3.2.3 Pointers.

Comment: So you're asking about casting and nothing to do with threads?

Comment: Where did the code come from? It invokes undefined behavior, so explaining how it works is not really possible. But you may need more context to understand things like `(void *) 100` it might be well defined in the context of the book.

Comment: @MikeCAT Okay, understood.

Comment: @John3136 Yes, I am still reading about threads and kind of understanding it, but ran across this cast and it was the first time I see so...

Comment: @iharob There's a link to the chapter I got it from, and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is just passing a constant to the thread start_routine. As long as the start_routine does not dereference the pointer and casts it back to the original type (which the example does) then everything is fine.

The alternative to doing it this way is to create a variable, set it to the constant value and pass the address of the variable to the start_routine. In this example that can easily be done because any local variables declared in `main` will always stay in scope. But in the general it cannot be simply done using a local variable as the local variable can not be guaranteed to be in scope when the new thread gets to execute. A global variable, a function static variable or a dynamically allocated variable would need to be used. All of which are more complicated/expensive to use and manage.

One argument against the above code is that cast to/from pointers and integers is implementation specific (but not undefined behaviour). However, most compilers would do what you expect in this case. For example, [gcc says](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Arrays-and-pointers-implementation.html#Arrays-and-pointers-implementation):

> A cast from pointer to integer discards most-significant bits if the
>   pointer representation is larger than the integer type, sign-extends1
>   if the pointer representation is smaller than the integer type,
>   **otherwise the bits are unchanged**.
>
> A cast from integer to pointer discards most-significant bits if the
>   pointer representation is smaller than the integer type, extends
>   according to the signedness of the integer type if the pointer
>   representation is larger than the integer type, **otherwise the bits are
>   unchanged**.

(Emphasis mine).

Comment: But when running the code as is from the command line:
>gcc threads1.c -pthread
threads1.c: In function ‘mythread’:
threads1.c:5:11: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
   int m = (int) arg;

Comment: @billy_b29 That's a compile time warning not an error. It's saying that there **might** be a problem. There isn't in this case (at runtime) because the constant fits in both types. Technically should never cast like this. If you need to manipulate a pointer as an integer type then should use `uintptr_t` which is defined to always be big enough to fit any pointer. But yes, in theory what is being done is not perfect and some people would disagree with it (hence downvotes). I'm not necessarily advocating this approach but still think it is good to know why it works and why some might use it.

Comment: Here's a different emphasis:

"A cast from pointer to integer **discards most-significant bits if the pointer representation is larger than the integer type**, sign-extends1 if the **pointer representation is smaller than the integer type**, otherwise the bits are unchanged."

So, *technically*, the code is potentially broken on certain systems. Nonetheless, you shouldn't write code like this. Always use a pointer to a struct.

Comment: @cyphar You are perfectly correct. So definetely you can shoot yourself in the foot if not used correctly (but that can be said about many aspects of C). But in the example given and in many simple cases it does work. Again, I'm just trying to explain why it can work not necessarily telling everyone this is the best practice. Also, as a nit pick, it doesn't have to be a pointer to a struct. Can just be a pointer to a base type variable as well.

Comment: @AlanAu I didn't realize it was a warning till you said it, and it works now with output: 
100
returned 101
thanks my friend!

Answer (score 1):

Your code will cause undefined behavior in the line pthread_join. You are passing a pointer to int, yet the function requires a pointer to a void pointer: `void**`. The manual cast to ( void** ) will not make the code correct, under the C standard.

Ignoring that mistake, the conversion from an integer to a pointer is implementation defined, so *you*( since you didn't say which one ) must check how your implementation defines that.